# TFSBuild error message -access blocked?

Tags: tfsbuild

Our new build server is failing builds after the test run finishes, with the following error in the log when it tries to publish the test report:

> The drop share directory
>   "\devbuildserver2\Builds\Matrix5313\Matrix5313-2_20130411.9" could
>   not be accessed.

The path definitely exists but the puzzle is that the domain account that Team Build Service runs under has full control on every folder in that path, and Builds is also a share with full control for that account. Inside the bottom folder Matrix5313-2_20130411.9 is the complete build plus the usual BuildLog.txt, ErrorwarningsLog.txt, etc. It seems that whatever is trying to publish the test report is not permitted access - but if not the build service, what?

Can anyone advise what else needs to be done to enable the test report to be published and the build process to complete?

OS = Win7-64bit, using VS Team System 2008.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did resolve this issue, which appears to be an incompability between TFS 2008 and Windows 7. I worked around it by running a VPC on the build server, running Windows XP on that, as the drop location. It's a pain because we now have to leave the machine logged in so the VPC can run, but at least it works. MS support staff basically had no idea other than to spend a wedge more money to upgrade TFS to a later version. All this because we weren't 'allowed' to move XP from an old build server to a new one and consequently had to upgrade to Win7. Imagine if you had to replace your car with a new one every time the roads were re-surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your UNC path is missing a back slash `\` character at the beginning. This is also assuming `devbuildserver2` is a valid server, and the server is active, communicating on the network, permissions are correct, etc.

```
Current:
\devbuildserver2\Builds\Matrix5313\...

Should be:
\\devbuildserver2\Builds\Matrix5313\...
```

Comment: Thanks. Now you've pointed it out I see that, but in the build definition the staging share is correctly defined with a double slash, and the server name is correct (the defined staging path is \\devbuildserver2\Builds\Matrix5313). I can see in the log that otherwise the complete build and test run finishes successfully but the test report can't be published. So where is the publish path defined, if not as the staging path in the build definition?

Comment: I've checked that now and I think this website has removed the leading slash when I pasted it from the log file. The logfile definitely has the double slash.